# Disabling HTTP Keep-Alive in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to completely disable Keep-Alive in *Node.js* server, but `setKeepAlive(false)` does not have any effect. This is sample code:

```
var http = require('http')

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.end('Hello Node.js Server!')
})

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.setKeepAlive(false)
})

server.listen(8080)
```

As you can see, after opening http://127.0.0.1:8080, keep-alive header is present:
[image: browser-request]

Am I doing something wrong?

Info: I am running node *v10.1.0*, but it also does not work on *v8.11.2*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable HTTP Keep-Alive by setting `Connection: close` header. This is necessary because [Keep-Alive is enabled by default in HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616?spm=5176.doc32013.2.3.Aimyd7#section-14.10).

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'close')
    res.end('Hello Node.js Server!')
})
```

[`socket.setKeepAlive()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay) is for [TCP Keep-Alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#TCP_keepalive) instead of HTTP Keep-Alive, which are two different things. It's very confusing, but TCP Keep-Alive is for keeping an idle connection alive, and HTTP Keep-Alive is for reusing a TCP connection for multiple HTTP requests.